# How to estimate the pH of multi-component buffer (phosphate buffer in equilibrium with CO2 rich atmosphere)?

Tags: equilibrium, ph, buffer

I wonder how the pH of buffer solution can be estimated if buffer consists of several systems in equilibrium to the gas phase. For example, (based on growth medium for one of the bacteria) buffer contains:

- $\pu{3 mM}$ $\ce{KH_2PO_4}$
- $\pu{3.75 mM}$ $\ce{Na_2HPO_4}$
- $\pu{2.5 mM}$ $\ce{NaHCO_3}$
- solution is sealed in a glass container with a gas phase containing 80% $\ce{N_2}$ and 20% $\ce{CO_2}$ under $\pu{1 bar}$ overpressure ($\pu{2 bar}$ total pressure)
- liquid takes approx. half of the full volume of the glass container

To my understanding, there are simultaneously 2 buffer systems taking place (phosphate buffer and bicarbonate), but I don't get how to combine that in calculations.

Comment: You may find useful these links for text formatting ( not to be applied to titles ):
 [notation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [chem/math formula/equation formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: Consider:  0/ [H]+ iand [OH-] is negligible wrt other ions 1/ Initial concentrations H2PO4-/HPO4^2-  and HCO3-/CO2(aq,tot). 2/ Shift in concentrations for the 1st pair equals respective shift for the 2nd one. 3/ Concentrations for both pairs must lead to the same [H+]

Comment: You can always use the generally applicable approach of constructing the set of inventory and equilibrium equations, with simplifying approximations  by application of justified strong inequalities.